# Not able to trigger delegate methods from a framework in react native modules for iOS applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-modules

I am writing a react native project where I am trying to connect to a BLE device using [BGXpress](https://docs.silabs.com/gecko-os/1/bgxhost/framework/latest/sdk/ios/api-index) library via an iOS Application using [react-native-modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios).

I have been able to successfully discover the device and connect as well, but I am unable to trigger the [delegate](https://docs.silabs.com/gecko-os/1/bgxhost/framework/latest/sdk/ios/group-b-g-x-device#protocol-b-g-x-device-delegate-p) method '**stateChangedForDevice**' once the device is connected.

Can someone please help me out on how I can actually get the delegate method to get triggered.

Thank you.